# Get the 1st 5 largest values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to get the 1st 5 largest values from a numeric array...i have tried using the `rsort()` function to list the array values from highest to lowest but cant get a way to pick the 1st 5 from the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$a = array ( 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 10, 7, 6, 8, 0 );
rsort($a);
$largest = array_slice($a, 0, 5);
```

Comment: thank you @knittl and everyone else..array slice is just what i needed and that sorted my issue.

Answer (score 3):

[Check this out](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$array_b4_change=array("knittl", "limón", "naranja", "plátano", "manzana" , "vikas" ,"wazzzy");
rsort($array_b4_change);
```

Use

```
array_slice($array_b4_change, 0, 5);
```

Comment: will not work, the return value of `rsort` is bool; it modifies the passed array directly

Answer (score 2):

After you rsort just slice the array using [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$ouput = array_slice($array, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the array organized you could output it with

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    print $array[$i];
}
```

Comment: ...and to sort it you can use `rsort()` as other said.

Comment: True. Reason why i dident mention it here is that he said he already done that in the question post. Glad you pointed it out though :)