# Finding max value in array using recursion in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I know how to use loop to do this simple problem, but I want to play more with recursion. I trying to find max value in array using recursion with PHP. My basic idea is compare the first value of the array with the maximum value of the new array (made by remove the first value of the given array):

```
function find_max($arr)
{
    if ($arr = []) 
    {
        return 0;         // base case
    } else
    {
        if ($arr[0] > find_max(rest_of($arr)))
        {
            return $arr[0];
        } else
        {
            return find_max(rest_of($arr));
        }           
    }
}

function rest_of($arr)
{
    unset($arr[0]);                  // remove the first value of the array
    $arr = array_values($arr);       // re-index the array
    return $arr;
}
```

But when I run, it seems that it has infinite loop. "Undefined offset: 0"
Can anyone help me?

Comment: might be a silly question, might be I don't understand your problem. But why don't you simply loop through that array, save highest values (and it's index) in a var, compare, re-save, ..?

Comment: or do a sort by value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778564/get-the-1st-5-largest-values-from-an-array check this .....

Comment: Or just using [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)?

Comment: @jeff: I know using loop, I just want to try more with recursion

Comment: if you do that for learning/training purpose: If you unset the first entry of an array, the index of the others doesn't change.

Comment: I re-indexed it. you can see

Comment: nah, I overlooked that too. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of your base condition here,

```
if($arr = []){ ...
```

`=` is an assignment operator, not comparison operator. What you need here is a comparison operator `==`. So it should be,

```
if($arr == []){
```

**Furthermore**, you can change your base condition like this way,

```
if(count($arr) == 1){
    return $arr[0]; // base case
}
```

So your `find_max()` function should be like this:

```
function find_max($arr){
    if(count($arr) == 1){
        return $arr[0]; // base case
    }
    if ($arr[0] > find_max(rest_of($arr))){
        return $arr[0];
    } else{
        return find_max(rest_of($arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: ha! how could I overlook that!?

Comment: @Jeff Don't worry, it's happens with all of us. ;-)

Comment: so my answer is completely wrong... I'll delete it then ;)

Comment: thank you @RajdeepPaul: what's a silly error! And thanks for your recommended solution.